# Google Tag Manager - Handling Multiple Regions Within One Domain

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

A similar question to this has been asked already but didn't address my query.

My company are expanding into multiple territories. These will be located within the one domain (we'll say domain.com), but the other territories will be in multiple subdirectories, such as:

```
domain.com/uk
domain.com/in
domain.com/us
domain.com/ie
```

We will be using Google Tag Manager to track the performance of our multiple campaigns, landing pages, and website as a whole.

How would we handle the adding of the container to the site, so that we'll be able to track the performance across different regions?

Would we require one container for the whole of domain.com, or would we need separate containers for domain.com/ie, ../uk, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to create a separate view for each market in `Google Analytics`
You don't need a separate GTM container

1. Keep the default unfiltered view
2. For each region, create the filter specific to your filter

[Example from Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034773?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

That mostly depends if you are expecting to have a similar GTM setup for all your directories; in that case it would be easiest to use the same container for all. If you have broadly similar tags you can just switch tracking ids where necessary via lookup table variables that match tracking ids to directories.

If your county setups in GTM wildly differ it would probably be more maintainable to have different containers instead of writing lots of specific triggers and trigger exceptions.

So this is not so much a technical decision (both a single or multiple containers will work), and more a question of what tags you want to deploy per territory and how you want to organize your work. But most of the time a single container should be fine.

If you are a 360 Suite customer you could have a global container with all tags common to all directories, and set up "[zones](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/guide-zones-google-tag-manager-360/)" with the stuff specific to a territory that are loaded depending on the directory.